# Microsoft VBScript runtime error

Tags: vbscript

I have written my code in VBScript.I'm getting error in a particular part of my code shown below.

> [ActiveX Script Task] Error: User script threw an exception: Error Code: 0
>   Error Source= Microsoft VBScript runtime error
>   Error Description: Object required: 'REGroupSBUOps'
>
> Error on Line 85

```
'Declaring and connection string statements
strREGroupSBUOps ="sp_CPVarianceOpsReport6"
Set REGroupSBUOps = oDBCon.Execute(strREGroupSBUOps) 

Dim arr()
ReDim arr(6)

Dim i    
arr(0) = "REGroupSBUOps"
arr(1) = "DandBSBUOps"
arr(2) = "Tristate/Central/EastSBUOps"
arr(3) = "WestSBUOps"
arr(4) = "EastSBUOps"
arr(5) = "UKSBUOps"
If Not (arr(i).EOF) Then   ' <--error on this line
    'followed by other statements
```

Comment: `arr` is an array of strings. Strings don't have a property `EOF`. What is `arr(i).EOF` supposed to do anyway? What do you want to check with that statement?

Comment: strREGroupSBUOps is assigned with a storedprocedure and REGroupSBUOps is the resultset of the sp. Taking resultset names in array and condition is checked.

Comment: A string doesn't magically become a variable unless you use [`Eval`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0z5x4094.aspx) which I **strongly recommend against**. Besides, this looks like an [X-Y Problem](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/XyProblem) to me. Why can't you simply use the variable(s)? Please explain the actual problem you're trying to solve instead of what you perceive as the solution.

Comment: [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40216702/activexscript-expected-statement-error-in-line-255) this is my complete code.  I have stored procedures written, their records are stored in recordsets. I have to execute same set of statements to convert each recordset to separate excel workbooksheets. I took the recordset names  in  an array. Error occurs while fetching values from array. please help

Answer (score 0):

Put the code inside your `For` loop into a sub, along with the actual execution of the stored procedures. Pass the stored procedure calls and the names from your array as a parameters to the sub. Replace all occurrences of `arr(i)` with the name of the variable that takes the records returned by the stored procedure call (`rs` in my example below).

```
Sub ExportData(sp, name)
    Set rs = oDBCon.Execute(sp) 

    If Not rs.EOF Then
        sFileName1 = "\\CTSC00579895801\ime\MailReports\" & name & ".xls"
        Set oFSOExcelFile = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
        Set objExcel = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
        objExcel.Visible = True
        ...
        objExcel.Quit
        Set objExcel = Nothing
    End If
End Sub

ExportData "sp_CPVarianceOpsReport 1" "Tristate_Central_EastSBUOps"
ExportData "sp_CPVarianceOpsReport 2" "UKSBUOps"
...
```

As further optimization you may want to create the Excel and FileSystemObject objects as global singletons and just handle the files inside the sub instead of creating and destroying those instances over and over again.